# Method reference with argument

Tags: java, java-8, currying

I'm looking for a way to map a tab separated String to an array. Currently, I'm doing it with a lambda expression:

```
stream.map(line -> line.split("\t"));
```

Is there a way to do it with a method reference?  I know that `stream.map(String::split("\t"))` does not work, but am wondering if there is an alternative.

Comment: You mean a reference to an existing method in the JDK? Because you can easily make a MyStringUtils::splitByTab and reference that.

Comment: I mean in general. I.e., whenever a method has an argument.

Comment: Ah, so you are looking for the Java equivalent of curried methods or Javascript `bind` (which can inject parameters). +1 for that.

Comment: I guess so (I hadn't heard of curried methods before). Misha seems to propose such a solution.

Comment: I assume you have a stream of tab-separated Strings, but what exact output type to you want? A single `String[]` with all of the individual split strings? Something else?

Comment: `split` is just a simple instance of a general need. Sometimes I need to do `stream.map(line -> line.indexOf("bla"));` or `stream.filter(line -> line.contains("bla"));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
static<T,U,R> Function<T,R> curry(BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, ? extends R> f, U u) {
    return t -> f.apply(t, u);
}
```

and then you'll be able to do:

```
stream.map(curry(String::split, "\t"));
```

Comment: You can simplify the signature by replacing `? super U` with `U` as the second parameter `U u` will accept subtypes of `U` anyway (this differs from `T` and `R` as these two are used by the return type).

Comment: This works, but this is like walking around the building to go next door; you're introducing a new abstraction just so you can use a method reference.  The code is clearer and simpler using a lambda.

Comment: Regardless of what the OP was trying to do, the following declaration would be truer to what currying is: `public static <T, U, R> Function<T, Function<U, R>> curry(BiFunction<? super T, ? super U, ? extends R> bf) {return t -> u -> bf.apply(t, u);}`.